# Magento2 : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ' ' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in Index.php

Tags: magento2

```
<?php

namespace Cloudways\MyModule\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;  

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /** @var PageFactory $resultPageFactory */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

     /**
     * Result constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $pageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Blog Index, shows a list of recent blog posts.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Custom Front View'));
        return $resultPage;

    }
}
```

Comment: have you remove var/generation folder from root?

Comment: please let me know if you have issue.

Comment: Yupp i tried but that folder was unable to remove.

Comment: Its create the issue when you have create new file with __construct method you have to remove var/generation folder to see new changes.

Comment: I remove var/generation folder but couldn't find any new changes

Comment: Have you clear cache?

Comment: Yes i cleared cache.

Answer (score 2):

it might be space issue. I am getting following error and resolved by removing space.

syntax error, unexpected ' public' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /var/www/html/mage2/app/code/Mymodule/Custommodule/Controller/Index/Index.php on line 6

Answer (score 1):

When you copy code from some web it includes special character in the lines you have to remove these invisible special characters from lines at beginning or ending. where error pointing like:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mage225/app/code/Progos/ThemeChanges/Observer/Product/Data.php on line 10
```

and

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$product' (T_VARIABLE) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mage225/app/code/Progos/ThemeChanges/Observer/Product/Data.php on line 21
```

Can be resolved by removing all before and after the line.